# Using a variable (not user inputted) in an SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to encode json for several fields of different tables in my database. Below is my code. I am currently using an array to represent the names of my tables ($tablename). I've read about SQL injections but they seem to focus specifically on user input. However, in this case there is no user interaction with my database. It's a backend for my app. Any thoughts on using variable names like this? Thanks

I also looked into prepare statements but it was quite difficult to fetch the data in the form i wanted.

```
<?php   

 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mmcv/buildchartInfo.php';

    $position = 0;
    $results = array();

    foreach($chartnames as $tablename) {

        print $tablename."<br />";

        encodejson($tablename);  


    }

    function encodejson($tablename){


    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mmcv/includes/connect.inc.php';

    $sql="SELECT rank, name FROM $tablename";


    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    //Error when data isn't returned
    if(!$result)
    {
        $output = "error getting data";
        echo $output;
        //$GLOBALS['loginError'] = "error getting log in data";
        exit();
    }


    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) $output[]=$row;

    print(json_encode($output));

    }

     mysqli_close($connection);

   ?>
```

Comment: Yes, why not. Do you have a real question here?

Comment: nothing wrong if you are **absolutely sure**

Comment: @fab sorry if the question isn't clear. I'm just trying to establish if there's anything wrong in variable names as shown above

Comment: In your case, `$tablename` should not contain any special characters because you neither escape them nor enclose the name in backticks. But if you have control over that, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule I'd suggest you to always use prepared statements even without user input. But technically speaking if you are absolutely sure the variable `$tablename` cannot be modified directly or **indirectly** (doesn't depends from other user inputted variables) then I guess it's fine to go with that.

**Notice**: table names cannot be prepared (`SELECT ... FROM :table WHERE ...` will not work), therefore sometimes you can't choose.

But sometimes its hard to track the real dependencies of a variable, therefore I still highly suggest you to with prepared statements.

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast, **notice** the edit I've forgot to add in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the user can't change the value of `$tablename`, then you have nothing to be scared about.